# How to find input by span in React-testing-library?

Tags: html, testing, input, react-testing-library

How can I find the checkbox for by text from span element? I can't modify my HTML.
I wish test fireEvent on input element.

`

```
<label>
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-extra-style">
      <span> SPAN A</span>
   </div>
</label>
<label>
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-extra-style">
      <span> SPAN B</span>
   </div>
</label>
```

`
....

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 8):

Span has no aria role, so you have a couple of options:

1. Modify the html adding an aria-role to the span, then use screen.getByRole
2. Let the HTML as it is, and following the [priority list](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority) use screen.getByText("SPAN A")

Comment: Thanks for tips Borja!

Comment: Upvote for the correct order of solutions according to RTL best practice

Answer (score 4):

You should use the extra options that are available in the `getBy...` queries.  For example, in this case, `screen.getByRole("checkbox", { name: /span a /i })`.  This will select

1. checkboxes by role on the page
2. filter the above down to the specific checkbox that has the text "SPAN A" associated with it ("SPAN A" will be the name since the span and the input are both inside the same label).

For additional help in finding out the right query to use for some given HTML, `testing-library`'s [testing playground](https://testing-playground.com/) is a great resource.

Answer (score 2):

try `const spanText = (await findByText('SPAN A')).parentNode.childNodes;`